# Increasing text size in buttons with react native ui kitten

Tags: react-native-ui-kitten

Suppose you have a button and the size of the button is perfect, but the text size doesnt match the size of the button.

How should i go about increasing the size of the Button text. Within the documentation it says to use, `StyleProp<TextStyle>`, ive been trying to use this but i feel like i lack the proper understanding.

A point in the right direction would be appreciated.

```
<Button
  status="control"
  appearance="ghost"
  size="giant"
> title </Button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you use custom font which doesn't look great with default configuration provided by Eva.
However, you have two options here. Providing text styles through the `textStyle` prop, or modifying mapping as I mentioned in related [github issue](https://github.com/akveo/react-native-ui-kitten/issues/918#issuecomment-593241216).

Answer (score 2):

The [button](https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/docs/components/button/overview#button) and its inner views can be styled by passing them as functional components.

```js
import { Button, Text } from '@ui-kitten/components';

<Button style={...}>
  {evaProps => <Text {...evaProps} style={{color: "red"}}>BUTTON</Text>}
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/docs/components/button/overview#button

Here is solution, you can change it by changing `size='giant'` for example, and set `height` and `width` of button in you styles, the text size will stay big from property `size`.

Or at the end of url is how to make it flexible for your code, if first option is not good solution.

I had same problem :)